# Why is Mavericks loading the wrong profile the first time I login?

Tags: macos, login, user-profiles, osx-mavericks

I'm on an iMac which was recently upgraded to OSX 10.9.1 Mavericks. There are two users accounts, which both use it regularly. It only happens with one of the accounts:
After a clean start-up, when I login with my credentials, it will load the wrong settings. The reason that I know this is:

- wrong wallpaper (I have it customized, but first time it shows default)
- wrong iTunes Library (empty actually)

However, some of my settings seem to be maintained:

- correct number of desktops
- correct applications are opened (which were open the last time I logged out)

If this happens, I force quit whatever is running, and log out immediatly. Then I login again and everything is fine. Even applications (eg iTunes) which I had force closed, are opened correctly again. It also usually happens when the other user is already logged in.

This is very strange behavior, and I don't even know where to start looking. Why is it loading the wrong settings?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is a problem you can solve on your own. Is sounds like a bug. Did you reported this to the official Apple Community?

Did you restored on of the users (or both) from an older backup or did you a clean install with both users?